# Как подсчитать количество элементов до элемента с классом 'active'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child active'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

на jQuery или JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var countBeforeActive = $('.child').index($('.active'));

console.log(countBeforeActive);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child active'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

[index()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5) - возвращает индекс заданного элемента в наборе.

Т.к. нумерация начинается с нуля, то индекс активного вернет, по сути, количество элементов *ДО*.